# hbase shell command - scan and Filter

Tags: shell, filter, command, hbase, database-scan

I am pretty new to Hadoop and hbase. Can anybody help me with the scan and filter command.

I was trying to pull the records in hbase for a range of rows and for a particular drug, using Filter. 
When I am giving this shell command: `scan 'Mytable', {COLUMNS => ['abc'], FILTER => "avil",STARTROW => "1100",STOPROW => "1121"}`

It is showing me an error as: `Incorrect Filter String`

I am trying to use this command as a reference:

```
 hbase> scan 't1', {FILTER => "(PrefixFilter ('row2') AND (QualifierFilter (>=, 'binary:xyz'))) AND (TimestampsFilter ( 123, 456))"}
```

can somebody please help me explain what is Prefixfilter and QualifierFilter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've gone through some basics of Filter and scan shell commands in hbase and found that SingleColumnValueFilter is perfect for filter cells based on value. Below command worked for me:

scan 'Mytable', {COLUMNS => ['abc'], FILTER => "SingleColumnValueFilter('abc','drug',=,'binary:avil')",STARTROW => "1100", ENDROW => "1121"}